# Display text on MouseOver for image in html

Tags: html, image

I would like to display text when the user mouseovers the image.

How can I do this in HTML/JS?

Answer (score 319, accepted):

You can use `title` attribute.

```
<img src="smiley.gif"  title="Smiley face"/>
```

You can change the source of image as you want.

And as [@Gray](https://stackoverflow.com/users/179850/gray) commented:

You can also use the `title` on other things like `<a ...` anchors, `<p>`, `<div>`, `<input>`, etc. 
See: **[this](http://w3schools.com/tags/att_global_title.asp)**

Comment: You can also use the `title` on other things like `<a ...` anchors, `<p>`, `<div>`, `<input>`, etc..  See: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_title.asp

Answer (score 18):

You can use CSS `hover`:

```css
div {
  display: none;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  height: 30px;
  width: 290px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

a:hover+div {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<a><img src='https://placekitten.com/100/100'></a>
<div>text</div>
```

Answer (score 6):

You can do like this also:

HTML:

```
<a><img src='https://encrypted-tbn2.google.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQB3a3aouZcIPEF0di4r9uK4c0r9FlFnCasg_P8ISk8tZytippZRQ' onmouseover="somefunction();"></a>
```

In javascript:

```
function somefunction()
{
  //Do somethisg.
}
```

​

Answer (score 4):

You can use CSS hover in combination with an image background.

```css
.image {
  background: url(https://placekitten.com/100/100);
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  display: block;
  float: left;
}

.image a {
  display: none;
}

.image a:hover {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="image"><a href="#">Text you want on mouseover</a></div>
```