# Problems to get address using onmouse over

Tags: javascript, jquery, get, href

What is the best way get address value from `<a>` tag using onmouseover event?

```
<a href="http://facebook.com" onmouseover="">something</a>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Display text on MouseOver for image in html](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12105214/display-text-on-mouseover-for-image-in-html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<a href="http://facebook.com" onmouseover="alert(this.getAttribute('href'))">something</a>
```

[Working demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/k29gno5b/)

You can store this result in variable using following code:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('a')[0].onmouseover = function() {
    var hrefValue = this.getAttribute('href');
    alert(hrefValue); // use hrefValue
}
```

[Working demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/k29gno5b/2/)

Comment: Maybe you can say how to store this result in variable?

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="http://facebook.com" onmouseover="alert($(this).text())">something</a>
```

`$(this).text()` gets the text between `a` tags, and `alert` pop ups the alert box with the value to make sure it works. Alternative would be to `console.log()` the value. This way is not that intrusive.

Comment: Please consider editing your post to add more explanation about what your code does and why it will solve the problem. An answer that mostly just contains code (even if it's working) usually wont help the OP to understand their problem.