# Use alt text for hover effect

Tags: jquery, html, css, alt

I'm trying to create a hover effect for images but I cant add a title on the img tag. So I was thinking to use the alt text attribute for the title on hover effect.

```
<img width="300" height="169" src="300x169.jpg" class="attachment-medium" alt="sometexthere">
```

Is there any jQuery plugin I can use or any other method to extract the alt text and use it?

Comment: _"I cant add a title on the img tag"_ Why not?

Comment: Just create a little DIV that stays hidden.  When you rollover the image, trigger a JS function that populates it with text, and sets its location near where the mouse is.

Comment: The `alt` is meant to be displayed when the image can't be displayed.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12105214/display-text-on-mouseover-for-image-in-html

Comment: @Anthony i read that question was not i was asking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like the comment, I am not sure why you can't add a title, either in the code or after the fact.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("img").each(function(){
        $(this).attr("title", $(this).attr("alt"));
    });
});
```

This would create a title for the image, in the case of not being able to modify the text code itself. You could also make use of JQuery UI to make Tool Tip: https://jqueryui.com/tooltip/

Can also use `.hover()` to make your own custom tip: https://api.jquery.com/hover/

Comment: Im trying to add a custom CSS, but as I am using wordpress with some plugins cant write on this piece of code. thnx for the solution

Comment: you can't write on this piece  of code but you still accept the answer?

Comment: @dippas I think OP means that they cannot edit the code. Maybe it's coming from legacy DB, such that `img` is just lacking `title` attribute, but does have `alt`.

Comment: sorry I meant that I cant write one the img tag to add the title there

Answer (score 1):

What about using a tooltip? Here is the css:

```
    #tooltip {position: relative; display: block;}
    #tooltip a span {display: none; color: #FFFFFF;}
    #tooltip a:hover span {display: block; position: absolute; 
        width: 250px; background-color: #048042; left: 300px; 
        top: -10px; color: #FFFFFF; padding: 20px; 
        border: 4px solid #c4c3c3;}
    #tooltipBottom {position: relative;}
    #tooltipBottom a span {display: none; color: #FFFFFF; }
    #tooltipBottom a:hover span {display: block; position: absolute; 
        width: 250px; background-color: #520e4e; left: 300px; 
        top: -300px; color: #FFFFFF; padding: 20px; 
        border: 4px solid #ffffff;}
```

You will want to play around with the position, width, borders, colors, fonts, etc. until you get it to look the way you want it to look.

Here is the html:

```
    <p id="tooltip"><img src="YOURIMAGE" /><a href="#" 
        style="text-decoration: none;"><img src="TOOLTIPIMAGE" alt="" 
        width="20" height="20" border="0" style="margin: 2px 0px 0px 
        2px" /><span>DESCRIPTION YOU WANT SHOWN</span></a></p>
```

The nice thing about this is that it does not depend on javascript and you can use it with text, images, etc. I have used it in the past for churches that wanted hove popup references for scriptures, i.e. a references to John 3:16 would show a popup with the text of the verse.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @durbnpoisn, you can create a `div` and set `show/hide` on `mouseover`-`mouseout` to give a `tooltip` effect.

```
<img width="300" height="169" src="300x169.jpg" class="attachment-medium" alt="sometexthere">
    <div></div>

$('img').mouseover(function()
{
  $('div').text($(this).attr("alt"));
  $('div').show();
}).mouseout(function()
{
    $('div').hide();
});;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/1fe1sanv/1/