# Javascript: Show one element, hide another

Tags: javascript, html, hide, show-hide

Taking a web design course, and need to use strictly Javascript on this project.

Basically I want to have a series of thumbnails on the left of the screen, and when one is hovered over it brings up information about the image on the right side of the screen. It remains that way until another thumbnail is hovered over, then the information is replaced.

I thought of having a series of divs on-top of eachother containing the information, and onhover the targeted div appears and the last div disappears.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please try it and when you have actual code and are having problems with making it work, ask questions then. This question is far too broad per guidlines explained in help center

Answer (score 0):

Give the images a mouseover attribute and run a function on hover.

```
<img onmouseover="changeInfo(0)">
<img onmouseover="changeInfo(1)">
<img onmouseover="changeInfo(2)">
<div id="showInfo"></div>
```

Then place the info for every image in an array and change the inner html in the div depending on which image is being hovered.

```
function changeInfo(index){
    var texts = ['Info on img0','Info on img1','Info on img2'];
    var info = document.getElementById('showInfo');
    info.innerHTML = texts[index];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the result you want to get. First, I declare all the images using divs. The information is hidden at the beginning.

```
<div id="posts">
  <div id="post1">
    <img src="[Insert an image]" width="100" height="100"/>
    <p class="hide"> information about picture one </p>
  </div>
  <div id="post2">
    <img src="[Insert an image]" width="100" height="100"/>
    <p class="hide"> information about picture one </p>
  </div>
  <div id="post3">
    <img src="[Insert an image]" width="100" height="100"/>
    <p class="hide"> information about picture one </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

these are the css classes

```
.nolabel p {display: none;}

.label p { display: block; }

.hide { display: none; }
```

and javascript:

```
var posts = document.getElementById("posts").children;

function forEach(el, callback) {
  for(var i = 0; i <= el.length; i++) {
    callback(posts[i]);
  }
}

forEach(posts, function(child) {
  child.addEventListener("mouseover", function(){
    forEach(posts, function(el) {
      if(child.id === el.id)
        el.className = "label";
      else 
        el.className = "nolabel";
    });
  });
});
```

the **forEach** helps us to simplify a this code a little.

> Since we could have any number of images I thought it was not a good
>   idea to reference each of them by its id.

When the cursor hovers over one of the images we trigger a mouseover event which will compare the ids. The if statement makes sure we only modify the element we clicked and the others remain with the nolabel class (or replace it if they had label). 
I hope that helps.

Answer (score -2):

jQuery would be best for this, or you can use an onMouseOver function and your information styled with visibility: hidden.  Maybe post some code so more help can be provided.

Check this out too [Display text on MouseOver for image in html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12105214/display-text-on-mouseover-for-image-in-html)