# Change text of a <span> when hover over <img> with image's caption | js / jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, hover, onmouseover

I have some `<img>`, like a gallery and a `<span>` tag below.

What I am trying to achieve is when I hover over one image to show some specific text on the same place each time. I have no idea how to do this one, even if it sounds simple!

Example

```
<img src="1">
<img src="2">
<img src="3">
<img src="4">

<span><span>
```

when I hover over img 1, I want the `<span>` to be like

```
<span> caption for img 1 </span>
```

when i hover over img 2,

```
<span> caption for img 2 </span>
```

...and so on

Comment: Can you enter some of your current code (the gallery) so we can see how he img/captions are structured

Comment: It doesn't sound simple at all to me :) Please, can you provide more details on what you are trying to do and also some code? Than we will be able to help you.

Comment: @seesae: Please add some effort and code as shown in the [help]

Comment: better duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12105214/display-text-on-mouseover-for-image-in-html