# Putting text on image doesn't work with CSS position property

Tags: html, css

I am developing a portfolio website. I tried to put some text over an image. I put the picture (`#projet-indiv`) in `position: relative` and the text (`#texte_projet`) in `position: absolute`.

```css
.projet-indiv {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-around;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 60px;
}

.texte-projet {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 15;
}

.images-projet {
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="images-projet">
  <img src="https://placekitten.com/300/230" style="height: 230px; width: 300px;">
  <div class="texte_projet">
    <p>Projet</p>
  </div>
  <p> Dataviz</p>
</div>
```

[image: render]

Comment: In the HTML you use `class="texte_projet"` in the CSS you write `.texte-projet`. Difference using *underscore_* vs.  *dash-* Typo!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Display text on MouseOver for image in html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12105214/display-text-on-mouseover-for-image-in-html)

Comment: Hello Michael, not really. I want simply put the text on image with position property and possibly z-index property.

Answer (score 1):

Link to main stackoverflow answer : [Display text on MouseOver for image in html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12105214/display-text-on-mouseover-for-image-in-html)

The simplest solution for you is to use `title` attribute :

```
<img img src="/images/Capture d’écran 2023-01-27 à 11.52.29 AM.png" style="height: 230px; width: 300px;" title="Projet :  Dataviz"/>
```

Or else to use CSS hover :

```css
div {
    display: none;
    border:1px solid #000;
    height:30px;
    width:290px;
    margin-left:10px;
}

a:hover + div {
    display: block;
}​
```

```html
<a><img img src="/images/Capture d’écran 2023-01-27 à 11.52.29 AM.png" style="height: 230px; width: 300px;" /></a>
<div>Projet :  Dataviz</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Apart from spelling the class name correctly, you need to use position parameters like `top` or `bottom` and `left` or `right` (all in relation to the relative-positioned parent) to **place**  the absolutely positioned text where you want it:

```css
.projet-indiv {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-around;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 60px;
}

.texte-projet {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 30px;
}

.images-projet {
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="images-projet">
  <img src="https://placekitten.com/300/230" style="height: 230px; width: 300px;">
  <div class="texte-projet">
    <p>Projet</p>
  <p> Dataviz</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hello everybody, I found my problem. I named badly my class containing the text. Since very long time I look for this problem but thank you to everyone.